# Bullet list collision isn't colliding with enemy list

Tags: c#, list, collision, detection

Okay, so I'm making a 2D platform game and I'm coming to the finishing stages. I've got the bullets firing, and my AI working etc. However I'm having an issue where when I try and see if the bullet's bounding box is colliding with the enemies, then it should kill the enemies. However they don't collide - I have to checked by console.writeline to see if the boundingbox for the spell is getting updating, which it is, and the same for the enemy. the code for the collision is this:

```
        foreach (EnemyClass enemy in enemies)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < spells.Count; i++)
            {
                if (enemy.collisionBox.Intersects(spells[i].boundingBox))
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Collision");
                    enemy.enemyHP -= spells[i].damageToDeal;
                    spells.ElementAt(i).isVisible = false;
                }

                if (enemy.enemyHP == 0)
                {
                    enemy.isAlive = false;
                }
            }
        }
```

This is the Update function that is in the spell class:

```
public void Update(GraphicsDevice graphics)
{
    boundingBox = new Rectangle((int)position.X, (int)position.Y, 15, 15);
}
```

Comment: Does it work sometimes or is always failing?

Comment: Have you tried drawing the bounding boxes to see if they move also? Is this xna/mono?

Comment: What are the boxes? Have you tsted spell.boundingBox.Intersects(enemy.collisionBox)?

Comment: Pawel - Yes it does always fail. I had a console.writeline within the intersects if statement.

Sayse - Yes I've used console.writeline and output the coordinates of the bounding boxes, they do indead move.

Nathan Cooper - I assume you mean have I put a console.writeline in that if statement to see if it works. I have done that and no it doesn't work. The boxes are rectangles. 

(I have collision working using the same boxes against other things elsewhere in the game)

Comment: The code you have included won't really show the issue, I'd imagine it comes down to how you are moving the bounding boxes, This will become evident if you draw them to the screen

Comment: @Sayse - Well I move them simply by calling an update function inside the enemy class and spell class, and creating a new rectangle and replacing the old one based on the new position. I know they work because, for example, all the enemies in the list of enemies colliding with each other and the player based on the same bounding box as in this code, and that works perfectly fine, which is why I assume the problem is in the code I've included.

Comment: Can you include the (relevant) code from the `Update` for the spell? if the enemies can collide then it sounds like its probably an issue there, the code you have shown should just allow a simple collision.

Comment: @Sayse - I've updated the original post to include it

Comment: Do the bullets move so fast that they go right through the enemy without being checked?  IE one frame is before the collision, the next frame is after?

Comment: @JamesThorpe - I'm not actually sure there, I could try slowing the bullets down and see what happens.

Comment: (Also from a code structure point of view, you might want your `EnemyClass` to set it's `isAlive` property itself when the `enemyHP` property reaches 0, rather than rely on other code doing so)

Comment: Its unclear, the code you have shown shouldn't give you the issue you are having, You should try to draw the bounding rectangles to the screen to see where they are.. it might help to easily see the issue

Comment: Yeah James, I see what you mean, thanks.

@Sayse - I'll draw them now and see what happens.

Comment: @Sayse - I've done it so when I draw to the screen I see the wireframe of the boundingbox (I think this is what you meant) and they do move accordingly) - do you think that perhaps there is a problem that the enemy bounding boxes overlap slightly so this causes the intersect to never happen? Because that's what seems to be the problem.

Comment: What exactly is the `Intersects` method?  The [`Rectangle` class doesn't have it itself](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Drawing.Rectangle_methods(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: And is the enemy collision box in the same absolute coordinate space as the bullet, or is it perhaps stored as an offset from the enemy's position?

Comment: @JamesThorpe - I'm using XNA/Mono so when I do boundingBox. it is one of the options there - what it basically does it checks to see if the boundingBox has intersected whatever is inside the (), in this case the enemies boundingBox & I'm not quite sure what you been by being stored as an offset? They're two separate classes, both move independently of one another, so as soon as the bullet hits the enemy, the enemy should take damage.

Comment: The bullet collision box is calculated in the `Update` statement as shown, using the current position + 15.  What _exactly_ is `enemy.collisionBox`?  Is it a rectangle that is based on the enemies position and updated in the same way, or is it just a rectangle of a given size saying how big the box is, but not at any particular coordinates, eg `new Rectangle(0, 0, enemyWidth, enemyHeight)`.  If the latter, it won't intersect.

Comment: @JamesThorpe The update method for the enemy collisionbox is identical to that of the spells, it creates a new rectangle every time based on the new coordinates of each enemy in the list.

Comment: @Peter - that would only be a problem if the logic for your enemy collision forces the enemy to move out of intersection with the spell before you get to the collision code for the spell.. How do you determine there hasn't been a collision? have you set a breakpoint in this intersection code that isn't hit?

Comment: @Sayse I have console.writeline's that tell me the current coordinates of the spell and enemy boxes and also one inside the if statement that will output if they intersect to say 'collision has happened'

Comment: I have slightly modified the main collision part of what I'm trying to do (See original post for the updated version)

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it - thanks for peoples help. It was a problem with the y-coordinate of the spells bounding box - I never thought to check it since collision in my game is all based around the x coordinate